# INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS how to overcome

Tags: android

When installing my app to Android L preview it fails with error:

INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS.

My app uses arm only library, features that uses library is disabled on x86. It works perfectly before Android L, but now i can't even install it. How to disable this error for my app?

Comment: check this link for latest Android same issue : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49473570/3400991

Answer (score 29):

Posting this because I could not find a direct answer and had to look at a couple of different posts to get what I wanted done...

I was able to use the x86 Accelerated (HAXM) emulator by simply adding this to my Module's `build.gradle` script Inside `android{}` block:

```
splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'
            universalApk true
        }
    }
```

Run (build)... Now there will be a `(yourapp)-x86-debug.apk` in your output folder. I'm sure there's a way to automate installing upon Run but I just start my preferred HAXM emulator and use command line:

```
adb install (yourapp)-x86-debug.apk
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the thread starter wants build a single APK with an optional native libary, which will only be loaded on ARM devices. This seems impossible at the moment (only using splits/multi apk). I'm facing the same issue and have created a [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=199332).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10989038)

Comment: It does potentially help to clear up the question by redirecting users to the bug report that might yield a solution soon. I'd have made it a coment, had I only had enough reputation then.

Answer (score 3):

This problem also come with when working with unity also. The problem is your app uses ARM architecture and the device or emulator that you are trying to install the app support otherwise such as x86. Try installing it on ARM emulator. Hope that solves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

In your `application.mk`, try to add `x86` at

> APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a

and it should be look like this

> APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a x86

Comment: What is the location of application.mk ?

Comment: Where is the location of that file

Answer (score 2):

You can find your answer in 
[INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS when install apk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24572239/1442180)

> INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS is when you are trying to install an app that has native libraries and it doesn't have a native library for your cpu architecture. For example if you compiled an app for armv7 and are trying to install it on an emulator that uses the Intel architecture instead it will not work.