# INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS error on Android 8

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-8.0-oreo

I am trying to build my app connecting my Pixel phone. I recently upgraded my phone to Android 8. I was able to build and open the app in my phone until the last upgrade, but after this upgrade, I get **Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]**
error.

Below is my gradle file. Can someone please tell me what is the issue ??

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.app.googlemaps"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'
            universalApk true
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
...
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Same issue here, debug apk is throwing this error but release apk works fine.

Comment: I have the same problem. has anyone found a solution?

Comment: The issue was with one of the apache libraries that I had used. After removing it, the app got installed

Comment: @nikhiln can you please mention which library? I am using POI and Math.

Comment: @user3471194 I was using apache library

Comment: Check if you are referencing correctly the maven libs, that fixed my issue.

Comment: Debug apk is throwing this error, but release is OK. The problem in my case was with signalR jar file, that included lib directory with .ps1 .sh and . jar file.
Excluding them with packingOptions in gradle fixed this. Why signing the apk solves the problem? No clue...

Comment: I just encounter this problem take at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51146016/180284

Comment: For me, workted what suggested here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51146016/704872

Answer (score 23):

It had the same problem, it worked after *replacing* an apache library (commons-io) with a different commons-io, that was from another bundle.

The problem occured to me after switching to a new development device (Pixel Phone w/ Android 8.0 Oreo).

## Solution 1

In your case, you could stop using your local jars from the filesystem (`compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')`) and use proper gradle dependencies from bintray (e.g.).

### Original gradle dependency (threw the same error that you describe):

**ERROR:** `Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]`

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
    compile 'commons-cli:commons-cli:1.4'
}
```

### Working `build.gradle` with proper `commons-io` artifacts:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.5'
    compile group: 'commons-cli', name: 'commons-cli', version: '1.4'
    ...
}
```

> Ignore the different dependency notation, it doesn't matter

## Solution 2

You define multiple target ABI, did you check, which one your device supports. Perhaps you have to add another one, to be compatible to your device ABI.

You can define them in the [`Application.mk`](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/application_mk.html)

**Also see:**

- https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html
- https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/application_mk.html
- http://androidlad.blogspot.com/2016/10/installfailednomatchingabis-when.html
- [[INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36414219/install-failed-no-matching-abis-failed-to-extract-native-libraries-res-113)
- [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS when install apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572052/install-failed-no-matching-abis-when-install-apk)

Comment: Avoid comments like +1 or thanks, nah. +1 and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips', 'mips64', 'arm64-v8a'
        universalApk false
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add a little explanation too