# INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS on Emulator Oreo and Real Device also

Tags: java, android

No problem on running other devices lollipop,marshmallow,nougat emulators and real devices. Oreo 8 doesnot support. showing this error INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS .

gradle below

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {

compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'


defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.paulcart.administrator.wibslink"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 26

    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
 }
}

dependencies {

implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
 core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-
  annotations'
})
compile files('libs/PhotoUtil.jar')
compile files('libs/GenAsync.1.2.jar')

compile 'com.wajahatkarim3.EasyFlipView:EasyFlipView:1.0.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
compile 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.4.3'

}


android {
   useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

 }
 android { sourceSets { main { res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 
  'src/main/res/layout-land'] } } }
```

tried this to

```
   splits {
   abi {
    enable true
    reset()
    include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'
    universalApk true
  }
 }
```

However this did not work, in order to make sure that the problem was with the Oreo 8.0 Emulator and  I checked a OREO Real device too and problem still exists

Help me to solve this.

Comment: are you using native libraries?

Comment: Did you try to install apk generated with armeabi-v7a name?

Comment: @Sagar  NO.. NOT USED

Comment: @Harry yes tried..

Comment: Got the issue                                                                                             
   {     compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4' }

Answer (score 1):

8.0 is much more strict about what's in the lib folder

1. extract apk file, see what's under lib/
2. use packagingOptions to exclude non so files under lib/

example(in android block):

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar'
}
```

Reference: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65941637