# GenyMotion INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS

Tags: android, virtual-machine, genymotion

i have downloaded the ARM translator for my genymotion but it is not recieving the file when i drag it do the Virtual Machine as it should recieve...
can anyone help?

Comment: Try Patrick's answer in [This Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24751350/install-failed-no-matching-abis-how-to-overcome/33178914#33178914)

Comment: Thanku 4Jean but i found a rooted machine

Comment: try this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49473570/3400991 for **Android 3.0.1**