# Installing Facebook.apk on emulator

Tags: android, facebook, android-emulator

I get the following message when I try to install Facebook-11.apk on the emulator:

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS]
```

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572052/install-failed-no-matching-abis-when-install-apk) and it wasn't very helpful. My emulator's Image is Intel Atom (x86_x64) (API 21).

I've searched everywhere and can't seem to find a solution to this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: That answer is correct. The Facebook APK apparently has native code in it but no x86 version, so it can't run on an x86 emulator.

Comment: Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Try installing it on Genymotion

Comment: AFAIK, `Genymotion` is x86 emulator so it won't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For google searchers out there - Use Genymotion if you want to check your app with the Facebook app.

As mentioned - you can't install Facebook apk on Intel-based images.

Answer (score 2):

I did it on emulators from Android Studio. Basically you can use any ARM emulator but they are slow as hell, so I do not recommend them. In order to use x86:

1. Go to https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/facebook-2/facebook/variant-%7B%22arches_slug%22%3A%5B%22x86%22%5D%7D/ and download any app you like (but you will have to try some of them, e.g. first one at the moment I was writing this answer did not work on x86 emulator)
2. Download the selected apk.
3. Drag'n'drop it on the launched emulator.

Whooorey!