# INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS on GenyMotion

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-5.0-lollipop, genymotion

Im trying to install video kik app on Genymotion andriod 5 but i keep getting this error. can someone tell me how to get around that?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [INSTALL\_FAILED\_NO\_MATCHING\_ABIS when install apk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572052/install-failed-no-matching-abis-when-install-apk)

Comment: see this answer here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572052/install-failed-no-matching-abis-when-install-apk

Answer (score 8):

I solved this problem by：

1. downloading "Genymotion-ARM-Translation.zip"(u can google the zip file).
2. start and run my genymotion.
3. Drag  the zip file to the genymotion virtual device,Then click 'ok' button by Following the tips.Finally restart ur genymotion and it works for me.

or u can refer the:[INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS when install apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572052/install-failed-no-matching-abis-when-install-apk)

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed a duplicate of [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS when install apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572052/install-failed-no-matching-abis-when-install-apk)

Here's the [guide](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952) on xda-developers on installing ARM Translation package for x86 emulators like Genymotion/Andy.

Keep in mind that they cannot emulate graphics completely. If installing the app still gives you the error, then you should probably try [Bluestacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/)!

Answer (score 0):

go to app build.gradle file and add split tag like i did and your problem will be solved.

```
android {

compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.appname"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'
        universalApk true
    }
}
```