# Installation Failed Android Studio

Tags: android, mobile

I migrated a Eclipse project on AndroidStudio.
When i run it in AndroidStudio in an emulator

> Run application > Lauch emulator

i have the error :

```
Installation failed with message INSTALL_FAILED_NOT_MATCHING_ABIS
```

A screenshot here : http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=304520prob.png

I can run other project, there is no error but here, i have one.

Can you help me pls ? :(

Comment: Are you using native code / functions in your application?

Comment: I don't know, someone send me the project, and i want to run it :/

Comment: It is when you are trying to install an app that has native libraries and it doesn't have a native library for your cpu architecture. src : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572052/install-failed-no-matching-abis-when-install-apk

Comment: Ty Noorudding. How i can fix that ?

Comment: If you just want to run the application then try creating a new emulator with different CPU architecture.

Comment: Did you try to uninstall existing  and run again?

Comment: I want to run the application and after, change it. And at the end, have this application on my phone.

Amsheer : Of course, I tried. But i have always the same message.