# I tried to view an app on test object (a mobile app testing site) and when I did it said "INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS"

Tags: android

What do I do to resolve this issue?

I've tried changing the app file to ipa however it still had the same issue

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INSTALL\_FAILED\_NO\_MATCHING\_ABIS when install apk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572052/install-failed-no-matching-abis-when-install-apk)

Comment: Sorry What does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Genymotion Emulator than you have to download `genymotion-arm-translation_v1.1.zip` file and just drag and drop to that Emulator and restart that Emulator. Now, It will work.

It is basically Architectural problem. You can find above file very easily on internet and make sure to drag and drop that **ZIP file** do not extract it. Hope this will help.

Comment: Sorry I am not using Genymotion

Comment: On which emulator are you running android application?@CatherineLagoon

Comment: TestObject is the emulator I am using

Comment: Actually you have to just create an account on [Genymotion.com](https://www.genymotion.com/) and than you can download it for free for your personal use with limited features. If you need more features than only you have to purchase it.@CatherineLagoon

Comment: https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1HJoRbfweL43gUDKT021AWz-GD2aEbRv1W27mwVuim0A/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: This is what happens when I open Genymotion even though I have installed VirtualBox↑

Comment: Try to install Genymotion with Virtualbox. Which OS do you have? A Mac or Windows?@CatherineLagoon

Comment: Even when I installed with Virtual Box it still had the same issue

Comment: Please, Give me full configuration of your OS and what softwares you have installed in order to develop Android Application.@CatherineLagoon

Comment: I used Smartface app studio on Windows in order to create the android application

Comment: Actually I don't have much exp. in Smartface App Studio. You should try their developer forum.@CatherineLagoon

Comment: Thankyou for your time. :-)

Comment: Your welcome. I think you should use Android Studio instead if you want to build only Android Application with Genymotion as Emulator.@CatherineLagoon

Comment: I neither recommend you nor I think so.@CatherineLagoon

Comment: I'll just leave it