# Android - OpenCV error: Cannot load info library for OpenCV

Tags: java, android, opencv

I already setup OpenCV SDK in Android Studio (https://www.learn2crack.com/2016/03/setup-opencv-sdk-android-studio.html) but it seems I got this kind of error message.

```
05-12 03:30:08.819 5480-5480/my.xxxxx I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
05-12 03:30:08.925 5480-5480/my.xxxxx D/OpenCV/StaticHelper: Trying to get library list
05-12 03:30:08.926 5480-5480/my.xxxxx E/OpenCV/StaticHelper: OpenCV error: Cannot load info library for OpenCV
05-12 03:30:08.926 5480-5480/my.xxxxx D/OpenCV/StaticHelper: Library list: ""
05-12 03:30:08.926 5480-5480/my.xxxxx D/OpenCV/StaticHelper: First attempt to load libs
05-12 03:30:08.926 5480-5480/my.xxxxx D/OpenCV/StaticHelper: Trying to init OpenCV libs
05-12 03:30:08.926 5480-5480/my.xxxxx D/OpenCV/StaticHelper: Trying to load library opencv_java3
05-12 03:30:08.926 5480-5480/my.xxxxx D/OpenCV/StaticHelper: Cannot load library "opencv_java3"
```

I already include `opencv_java3` into `JNI` folder.

[image]

Comment: Hi, did you find the solution? I am battling with the same problem. I used the tutorial here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406303/opencv-in-android-studio ..

Comment: @Mohammad have you solved your problem i having the same problem can share your answer if you solved it?

Comment: someone in May 2020, and want to solve using deprecated ndk, Please add '  
 ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "armeabi", "mips"
        }'
inside defaultConfig(App level Gradle)
and add 'android.useDeprecatedNdk=true' inside gradle.properties.

Comment: I also have the same problem.. I'm using JavaCameraView and after 20 seconds it throw that message and reset the app

Answer (score 18):

If someone is still (March 2020) searching for this error -

```
 E/OpenCV/StaticHelper: OpenCV error: Cannot load info library for OpenCV
```

and ends up here on this StackOverflow discussion, here is a helpful clarification from the OpenCV contributor on their site itself.

> Ignore this error message. "Info library" is used for special Android
>   configurations, like builds with CUDA support.

Please see this (currently open) issue here - https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/15567

Answer (score 7):

Most online tutorial will tell you to add just `armeabi-v7a` and `x86_64` into your `jniLibs` folder, but this can cause errors in recent versions of OpenCV. The following briefly describes a few tweaks I used to fix this error when I was experiencing the same issue.

**Solution 1:**

Make sure the JNI folder you are placing the OpenCV libraries in is named `jniLibs`

[jniLibs Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rU7e.png)

**Solution 2:**

Copy *ALL* the directories found in `OpenCV-android-skd/sdk/native/libs` to your `jniLibs` folder.

[jniLibs folder with all OpenCV libraries added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iv0m.png)

**Recommended:**

Even though it is a separate issue involving the emulator, you should also add the code snippet posted by [FD3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43894529/9709476) in your app Module Gradle file. This will prevent the [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24572052/9709476) error from occuring after attempting to run your app on an emulator.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to include `opencv_java3` into `jniLibs` folder, like this:

[image: Android Studio Image]

Answer (score 1):

Over a year later but I found this to work for me.  In you app Module gradle file, add:

```
splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86_64'
            universalApk true
        }
    }
```

This should be put in with the android brackets.  Obviously adjust your includes for which ever you may need.

Answer (score 0):

possibly missing **libc++_shared.so** library that comes with the Android NDK as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/66692717/14019579.

**Solution**

1. Download the whole ndk or download [**libc++_shared.so**](https://github.com/urho3d/android-ndk/blob/master/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc%2B%2B/libs/armeabi-v7a/libc%2B%2B_shared.so)
2. copy this library to all the subfolders. [Your proj structure should look like this now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEoMC.png).

*doing this after the first link worked on Studio V4.2.1 and OpenCV 4.5.2*