# Gvr Controller Emulator can't be installed

Tags: android, google-vr

I downloaded the [Controller Emulator](https://developers.google.com/vr/concepts/controller-emulator) from the [Gvr github page](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-android-sdk/blob/master/ndk-beta/apks/controller_emulator.apk), but I cant install it on my Sony Xperia Z3 compact (API=22).

The installation over adb fails with this message: `Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS]`.

Do I need Android 6.0 or even N to install the app?

I was planning to run my app on an emulator running Android N and control it with my phone until an actual devkit comes out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to successfully install the controller_emulator.apk using Android 4.4 on my Droid X, so Android 6.0 shouldn't be required (although I installed a CM11 ROM in order to upgrade to Android 4).  Also, for hardware prerequisites, Google only [states](https://developers.google.com/vr/concepts/dev-kit-setup) that you need

> A second Android phone, running KitKat or above. These instructions were tested using a Nexus 5X.

But, it seems that the native binaries for the controller app might not be supported on the Z3 according to the error you are getting, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572052/install-failed-no-matching-abis-when-install-apk) on stackoverflow.

### Edit

There was a bug fix directed toward this exact issue.  You could also try updating to the latest controller emulator app.
https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-android-sdk/issues/88