# Android Studio emulator can neither install app nor delete it.

Tags: android, emulation

I have a problem with a particular app in android studio.

When I wanted to Run app it gave this error: 
**`Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS]`**
and asked like this:

[image]

I clicked OK button to uninstall it then it gave another error:

**`DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR 
Error while Installing APK`**

I can not uninstall the app manually from the emulator. The Settings -> App -> in the emulator does not show the application in the application list.

How can I erase the app or how can I make it work on emulator.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/24572239/5515371

Comment: no matching abi should be related to the architecture of the device