# Ionic 2 run android: Failed to load native library 'native-platform.dll' for Windows 10 amd64

Tags: ionic2, android-gradle-plugin

I'm working with ionic 2, and I get this error message while running 
`ionic run android` command.
`* What went wrong:
Failed to load native library 'native-platform.dll' for Windows 10 amd64.`

Full error message:
Unzipping C:\Users\XXX.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.14.1-all\4cj8p00t3e5ni9e8iofg8ghv
k7\gradle-2.14.1-all.zip to C:\Users\XXX.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.14.1-all\4cj8p0
0t3e5ni9e8iofg8ghvk7

FAILURE:
Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Failed to load native library 'native-platform.dll' for Windows 10 amd64.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option t
  o get more log output.

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Failed to load native library 'native-platform.dll' for Windows 10 amd64.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option t
  o get more log output.

Comment: any luck? got same problem

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572052/install-failed-no-matching-abis-when-install-apk 
I guess it has to do with architecture your app was built with?