# Android APK INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I've come today to the work and tried to run my project on the test phone I have.
Surprisingly I received the following error:

```
Installation failed with message INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113.
```

Yesterday the project was running without any problems and I didn't have any problems with it for months and suddenly this happens. I've watched the commits from git since yesterday but there aren't any changes in `gradle` files.

Tried to restart the computer, invalidate cache & restart and even clean the code, nothing helped.

I am running the latest version of android studio 3.0 and I also tried to update platform tools and build-tools.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INSTALL\_FAILED\_NO\_MATCHING\_ABIS when install apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572052/install-failed-no-matching-abis-when-install-apk)

Comment: I don't see it as a duplicate, the problem appeared without any changes of gradle files, tested on the same phone for months. tested on more than 1 phone and the problem still persists. I am going to investigate more.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add the following code in your *build.gradle* file:

```
android
{..........
splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'
            universalApk true
        }
    }
.............
}
```