# INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS while installing app on real device

Tags: android

I was trying to install my app on a real android device (Xiaomi note 4 and Nexus 7), but it shows the error as -

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]
```

Now this problem is discussed in many questions [Like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572052/install-failed-no-matching-abis-when-install-apk)
but all of them are talking about facing this problem on Emulators, so one can make emulator of appropriate CPU image (ARM or x86)

How can one fix that for a real device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need make sure if jniLibs folder are put correctly. Also make sure you have armeabi-v7a folder that contains .so files. armeabi-v7a has larger cpu set.

|--app:

|--|--src:

|--|--|--main

|--|--|--|--libs **(careful here, its the folder that we include later)**

|--|--|--|--|--armeabi-v7a

|--|--|--|--|--|--.so Files

|--|--|--|--|--x86

|--|--|--|--|--|--.so Files

Secondly, add this line if does not exist in your app `build.gradle`

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['.jar','.so'])
```

Do your homework and research the cpu architecture of your real device. So you can get whats missing.

Comment: Thank you, let me look into it.

Comment: i get the same problem but with different behavior , the app is working on all my devices of test , but since i did the oreo update on my s7 edge i got this error ! and  what it's wrong is even the app icon is gone after the oreo update! any help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51773192/install-failed-no-matching-abis-error-after-oreo-update