# INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS error after Oreo update

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I'm actually working on 3 android applications (A-B-C ) , everything is going fine on all my devices , but when i updated my S7 Edge to Oreo , something weird happened , 2 applications (A-B) disappeared , only C remains on my phone. 
So , i wanted to reinstall them by ADB , and i got this error :

**Installation failed with message INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113.
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.**

when i click on uninstall , i got this error :

**Unknown failure (at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:682))**

when i tried to reinstall the third application C which remains after Oreo update , everthing went fine .

So i just realized that something went wrong with that two application after Oreo update , it seems like A-B still exist on the device even though i can't find them , any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out why i got this issue .

In the `gradle.app` of the two application getting the issue (A-B) , i was using

```
apache.commons.io:2.4
```

i just removed this line from the app gradle

```
compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
```

and now everything is working fine again

this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46094281/install-failed-no-matching-abis-error-on-android-8) helped me a lot to figure out mine  .