# Installation failed no matching abis

Tags: android, android-studio, architecture, executable-jar

When I try to install app on higher versions of android like Android 6.0 and so on...
It gives error ,saying

**INSTALLATION_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS;
FAILED TO EXTRACT NATIVE LIBRARIES,res=-113**

But
My app perfectly runs on android 5.0 and 5.1

I am using third party libraries(.jar files) to accomplish my app's functionality,According to my vision problem is with these libraries.

***IMPORTANT***
 I created empty project and install app,everything is fine till now.
But when I put my required libraries in lib folder,it gives the error

[INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS when install apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572052/install-failed-no-matching-abis-when-install-apk)

I have applied the solution found here.but it did not worked for me

[I am using these libraries in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1brle.png)

Comment: please check my answer to the same question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51773192/install-failed-no-matching-abis-error-after-oreo-update

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INSTALL\_FAILED\_NO\_MATCHING\_ABIS error after Oreo update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51773192/install-failed-no-matching-abis-error-after-oreo-update)