# After updating android studio to version 3.0 (windows),then: INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS:

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

After updating android studio to version 3.0.1 (windows).
then I am not able to install apk  in emulator I am getting an error "

> Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed
>   to extract native libraries, res=-113"

In my project, I have not used any native lib or any native function.
 In my previous version(2.2), it working fine.that time i have not get any issue.

> INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS 
>           for above issue i have put below code in project app gradle File it's working.

```
splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips', 'armeabi', ' x86_64', 'mips64', 'arm64-v8a'
            universalApk true
        }
    }
```

> when i generate signed apk then their are create 7 different architecture build . it means i have to upload 7 diff build. in previous version(2.2) i have create only 1 Build, when i upgrade 3.0 then i have to create 7 diff build . how i can avoid this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INSTALL\_FAILED\_NO\_MATCHING\_ABIS when install apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572052/install-failed-no-matching-abis-when-install-apk)

Comment: @ Ibrahim Yes this is duplicate ,how i can avoid this creating 7 build ,becoz previous version i have not get any issue like this .

Answer (score 0):

[Remove NDK from SDK manger then it work perfectly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIyPo.png)