# INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS on API Level 26

Tags: android, arm, android-x86, android-api-levels

I am running into the `INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS` error only when I try to install the apk on an API 26 x86 based emulator.

The apk runs well in an ARM phone with level 24 and also runs well on an x86 emulator.

I tried already the fix suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33761604/3128369) with no luck.

Comment: try to clean and rebuild your project

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JNI, please verify if you have the libraries(.so files) built for the device/mobile architecture as well. As it says it can not find any matching ABIS means that the library is build for some architecture which doesn't match the architecture of Mobile.
Either run the apk on the device you have built the libraries for i.e. same architecture of mobile and .so files, or compile the libraries for that mobile architecture as well.