# app not running on other phones

Tags: android, build, android-emulator

> Installation failed with message INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS:
>   Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113. It is possible that this
>   issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it
>   is present, and then re-installing.

I check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572052/install-failed-no-matching-abis-when-install-apk) but it doesn't work for me, app is not running on other devices neither on emulator.
somehow it works on oneplus 5T Oreo but the feature i implemented is not working.

help me out here

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        classpath 'org.greenrobot:greendao-gradle-plugin:3.2.2'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'org.greenrobot.greendao'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hero.duit"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0.0'
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'build/generated/source/greendao']
    }
}

greendao {
    targetGenDir 'src/main/java'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    compile 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.1.1'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.8.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile(name: 'sinch-android-rtc', version: '+', ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: 'sinch-android-verification', version: '+', ext: 'aar')
    compile 'org.greenrobot:greendao:3.2.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: can you show build.gradle of the app.

Comment: @Vishu have a look