# How to install an apk file in AVD?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.4. I have an apk installed in my system and I want to install that apk file in the emulator(or AVD). I dragged and dropped the apk file to the emulator and I got the following error.
[Click here for the Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKcy8.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `adb` for that, just make sure you have in your PATH and type `adb install <path>/your.apk` Make sure your emulator is running with `adb devices`

Refer to this: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html

Comment: I am getting the error :                                                                     Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]

Comment: Read here then : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572052/install-failed-no-matching-abis-when-install-apk