# APK Fails to install when library with native components(`bitcoinj`) is included

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, android-library, bitcoinj

I have two projects, `A` and `B`. Both projects rely on `org.bitcoinj:bitcoinj-core:0.14.7`.

`A` is an older project from 2016, compiles fine and launches a debug-apk to my device or emulator.

`B` on the other hand, is a new project. `B` has a library module, `LibB` which actually contains the reference to `bitcoinj`. `B` runs just fine without including `libB` in the build.gradle. However, if I include `libB` in the `build.gradle` for `B`, Android Studio hangs on the `Install APK` step for 8-10 minutes before informing me `Session 'app': Error Launching activity`. Occasionally (inconsistently) I will get `INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS`, which I know from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572052/install-failed-no-matching-abis-when-install-apk) is caused by not having the correct native libraries for the cpu architecture.

Looking at the tasks that gradle runs for each project, I can see that project `A` performs NDK tasks, `:app:compileDebugNdk`, `:app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders`, etc. `B`, however, does not run these steps. I attempted to include `bitcoinj` in the root project, rather than through the library, and while those steps now execute, I still get the same result with `B`. I've even gone so far as starting a new empty project, `C`, and included `bitcoinj` in the dependencies, and it also fails to deploy to my device.

I've stepped through my `build.gradle` files, `gradle-wrapper.properties`, `gradle.properties`, `settings.gradle`, the gradle wrapper and other files not source, in the hopes of finding an inconsistency that would lead to these failed builds, however I haven't discovered any.

I realize this is a rather vague and complicated problem, and will be more than happy to update the question with any clarifications that may be missing.

All that said, what can I do to get my projects to compile?

=====EDIT=====

I have found [this issue on the bitcoinj github](https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj/issues/1544), but there are several issues with this approach it seems.

1. The `packagingOptions` block must be included in `B`'s build.gradle, not `libB`, which makes for complications when trying to distribute.
2. I have not included this block in `A`, and it still works. Very stumped.

Comment: Have you found a solution?  I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky I have not found a solution that doesn't involve requiring application developers using the library to include the packagingOptions block.