# Easiest Way to Deploy Xamarin Android App in VS 2017?

Tags: android, xamarin, android-7.0-nougat

I have an Android app that I made maybe like 2 years back. I never deployed it to google store as it really is just for me.

I deployed it on my phone and installed via apk or through VS itself (I can't remember).

I recently formatted my phone and now would like to get my app back. I still have the code and opened it in VS 2017, it did an upgrade of my project but I can't figure out how to deploy it to my phone.

I enabled developer mode but still can't figure it out. I tried to copy the apk that VS generated but when I try to install it, I just get "it is corrupt and can't install".

The app is extremely simple. It is one screen with 6 textboxes and 1 dropdown on it.

Just trying to get it back on my phone as fast as possible so I can use it.

I do get some error when I try to see if it will load on the emulator in VS 2017

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       ADB0010: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]
   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName)
   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass94_0.<InstallPackage>b__0(Task`1 t)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()     

0
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572052/install-failed-no-matching-abis-when-install-apk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only easiest way you are doing. Plug your device via USB cable & press F5.
I am sure you need to check all supported CPU architectures in Visual Studio.
Right click on your project- go to properties

Properties-->Android options-->Advanced-->Supported Architecures

- armeabi;
- armeabi-v7a;
- x86;
- x86_64

& check if available, uninstall your app from your real device
settings->apps->uninstall.

Hope it help you.