# Starting session in Appium

Tags: android, appium, appium-android

While starting a session in Appium, I am getting below error:

**Error:**

> *An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command 'C:\Users\satyajit.more\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 install 'E:\Appium Setup\MobileInsurance_QA_16062018.apk'' exited with code 1'; Stderr: 'adb: failed to install E:\Appium Setup\MobileInsurance_QA_16062018.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]'; Code: '1'*

Have configured an emulator using the android studio, but am unable to install the app on the emulator, How can we resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The apk file you are trying to install is incompatible with the device hardware. You would get the same error even if you install the apk manually on the device. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24572052/5551621) thread for more information.