# Could not install apk in genymotion

Tags: android, genymotion

I know that "Error while installing apk" it's a common error.I am using genymotion and I've created android 8.0 virtual device.My other apps are installing in this V.D except one app.It's using fb integration,youtube api etc..But when I'm trying to run it the error getting as

run:

> 10/23 13:08:38: Launching app $ adb push
>   /media/zinedroid/Zinedroid/Workspace/ATMADARSHANTV
>   01-10-18/ATMADARSHANTV/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-x86-debug.apk
>   /data/local/tmp/com.zinedroid.android.atmadarshantv $ adb shell pm
>   install -t -r "/data/local/tmp/com.zinedroid.android.atmadarshantv"
>   Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native
>   libraries, res=-113] $ adb shell pm uninstall
>   com.zinedroid.android.atmadarshantv Unknown failure (at
>   android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:674)) Error while
>   Installing APK

it's working in other virtual devices in genymotion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INSTALL\_FAILED\_NO\_MATCHING\_ABIS when install apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572052/install-failed-no-matching-abis-when-install-apk)

Comment: it didnt solve my problem

Comment: it suggests to install arm translation for genymotion.But arm translator is not installing inn android 8.0