# How to make native library optional

Tags: android, android-emulator, java-native-interface

I'm writing project which works with RFID scanner. SDK for this device uses native libraries which I put into `src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a`, `armeabi`, `armeabi-v7a`. This SDK does not have libraries for x86 architecture, so now I can't install this apk into emulator: installation fails with message `Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113`. Is there any way to make this optional, so I could still install it and test unrelated features on fast x86 emulator?

Comment: You can always create abstract class and one sub-class can implement it as native one, another as non-native one: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-no-030/ This way, you can easily define your env to work properly when you have native code, and fill it with dummy methods while working without native one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the system CPU before calling LoadLibrary, or catch the exception of LoadLibrary fails. You should isolate the RFID feature in a separate class that won't be loaded in your emulator tests.

Comment: I don't call LoadLibrary. The problem is that I can't even install this apk on emulator.

Comment: Installation failed with message Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113.

Comment: The easiest workaround is [to use splits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33761604/192373)

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm! Now my API call throws UnsatisfiedLinkError which I can process as needed.