# Error Running ARFoundation App on Android Emulator

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, arcore, android-augmented-reality

I have downloaded the ar foundation app from a course regarding AR Foundation on Coursera. https://www.coursera.org/learn/handheld-ar/
I have successfully run the app on my phone but my phone does not support ARCore, so I went for the emulator. I followed all the instructions on the ARCore Website. But When I install the apk from the unity project and drag-drop on the emulator it gives me **String Parse Error**

logcat shows:

> failed to install my_arr_app.apk: Failure
>   [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries,
>   res=-113]

Can anyone help how to resolve it or how to test my apps to complete the course successfully? Please guide!
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See the other answer for the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61208634/2232127)

---

The app is using native libraries compiled for a specific platform. There are multiple different platform types that android supports (`armeabi`, `x86`, `x86_64`, etc.). Depending on the emulator image you are using the app might not include the binaries for your emulator.

You can open the APK in Android Studio (or extract it as a zip) and have a look into the `lib` folder in the APK. Each subfolder is an architecture name.

Then you can create a new Emulator in the AVD manager and when choosing the system image, select "Other images" and choose one with an ABI which is included in the app.

Example:
[image: system image selector]

---

The answers from the following question also might provide some detail: [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS when install apk](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24572052/2232127)

Comment: lib says: armeabi-v7a, What to do with the emulator for it? I have a PIxel 2 XL Android 9

Comment: @Rehan create a new virtual device, select Pixel 2 (or Pixel 2 XL), click next, select "Other Images" and choose one which has ABI armeabi-v7a

Comment: My min sdk is android oreo and there Is no image for armeabi v7a for it? What to do? My app uses ARCore which also requires min sdk of Oreo

Comment: @Rehan Uhm... I guess you can't use the app like that then... What's the `.so` file named in the lib directory?

Comment: There are many .so files in armeabi-v7a (libacore, libunity, libmain) no .so file in lib only one directory!

Comment: @Rehan additionally, are you building the app yourself or where exactly have you downloaded it?

Comment: I have followed a guide on corsera. Build the app on Unity using ARFoundation toolkit

Comment: so I cant use it with emulator?

Comment: ARFoundation should support other architectures... Which version of ARFoundation are you using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211632/discussion-between-jensv-and-rehan).

Comment: Application installs perfectly on real device creates problem with emulator. My phone lacks arcore support else would never get into the emulator thing

Answer (score 0):

By the help of @JensV I managed to solve it by choosing the x86 instead of ARMv7.
Go to Edit->ProjectSetting->Player->Configuration->Select x86

Comment: There's no "Configuration" submenu in Unity3d

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsAndroid.html#Configuration