# QT5.14.0 Problems running Android apps

Tags: android, qt

After Completing the QT android configuration, I tested AVD with two different apis.There was no problem running the application with AVD using the default installed SDK API, but the following error occurred when I ran the application with AVD created by downloading the SDK API by myself:
[logs here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GG8pn.png)

The configuration of my SDK Manager and AVD Manager is as follows:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6CMr.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0Fem.png)
I would be most grateful if you could give me some advice from someone who knows how to solve this problem again.

Comment: take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24572239/530462