# Error: INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113

Tags: android-studio

When I Create Virtual Device Nexus 5X API 27 and install .apk file

occure problem in android studio event log. help me :(

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmXkz.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! A recomendation: to help people understand and reproduce your problem, it's better to copy-paste code and error output directly in the question (instead of a screenshot).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [INSTALL\_FAILED\_NO\_MATCHING\_ABIS when install apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572052/install-failed-no-matching-abis-when-install-apk)