# I m getting below error while installing apk in emulator device

Tags: android, automation, appium

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\platform-tools\\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 install C\://Users//Admin//eclipse-workspace//CUEDOS//src//test//java//resources//app-release-9jan.apk' exited with code 1'; Command output: adb: failed to install C://Users//Admin//eclipse-workspace//CUEDOS//src//test//java//resources//app-release-9jan.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]
 
Host info: host: 'DESKTOP-7FP2AUK', ip: '192.168.31.114'
Build info: version: '4.6.0', revision: '79f1c02ae20'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.3'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[{appium:deviceName=Oppo A54, platformName=ANDROID, appium:automationName=UIAutomator2, appium:app=C://Users//Admin//eclipse-workspace//CUEDOS//src//test//java//resources//app-release-9jan.apk}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {appium:app: C://Users//Admin//eclipse-w..., appium:automationName: UIAutomator2, appium:deviceName: Oppo A54, platformName: ANDROID}}]
Capabilities {}
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:146)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumProtocolHandshake.createSession(AppiumProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumProtocolHandshake.createSession(AppiumProtocolHandshake.java:102)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:155)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:189)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:541)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:229)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:157)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:80)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:92)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:117)
    at OPPO_A54.ab.main(ab.java:32)
```

Could you please help anyone here what should have to do ...?

Comment: It's a specific settings/device issue that is not really debugable. I can only point you to this appium github thread here: https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/16942

Comment: Hello, INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS indicates that your application uses some native libraries (so files) and there is no library variant included for the given device CPU architecture.
You can get more details in this thread.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572052/install-failed-no-matching-abis-when-install-apk