# Not able to install application using appium

Tags: android, appium, appium-android, appium-ios, appium-java

I'm trying to install the apk file through Appium on the emulator 5554. I'm receiving the following error, but the same apk file can be installed on a real device through Appium and it works.

```
Response code 500. Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command ''C:\\Users\\LENOVO IDEAPAD C340\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\platform-tools\\adb.exe' -P 5037
-s emulator-5554 install D:\\PROJECT\\qasfa\\resources\\appFile\\6.3.2.0.15.apk' exited with code 1'; Command output: adb: failed to install D:\PROJECT\qasfa\resources\appFile\6.3.2.0.15.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]
```

Note: emulator-5554 #pixel 6 pro Android 13 ( playstore available).

Comment: Just posting an error message without description what you are trying to do and what you have already tried to bypass the error isn't good style. And last but not least please don't post everything into one line. You can format error message say code then line breaks will be shown exactly as you copy it junk the question.

Comment: Hi Robert, I'm trying to install .apk file on android pixel api 33 emulator using appium but appium throwing error 500,INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]

Comment: Please edit your question and update so other users just have to read the question and not also all comments.

Comment: Bro question ah Edit pannuga bro, Neega enna try pannanga, enna error vanthuchu, Etha run pandra pa vanchunu thani thaniya podunga.

Comment: Hi Sanjay,I'm trying to install the apk file through Appium on the emulator 5554. I'm receiving the following error, but the same apk file can be installed on a real device through Appium and it works.

Answer (score 0):

As an error says [`INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS`] the reason should be **mismatching ABI architecture**, meaning that your `.apk` file does not contain ABI configuration supported by emulator. To solve an issue:

- Try switching to a compatible emulator (ARMv8, x86, etc.).
- Ask developers for the build with compatible ABI for your emulator.

Please see [answer to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24572239/3944564).